# Project Blank App using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova not build

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I installed Visual Studio Tools environment for Apache Cordova, follow all MSDN guidelines correctly, however when I create a Blank App and give the build he insists on returning the error that I have attached a picture. I've tried some solutions I found on the internet yesterday and even uninstalled every environment and installed again, but the error persists. I suspect it is related to the wrong path when calling the nodevars.bat file but do not know where to set the correct path. Does anyone know what this is?

Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(103,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Users\Diego_Bertelli\Documents\Diego\Dev_Cordova\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5): error : 'MySQL' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5): error : ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5): error : 'MySQL' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5): error : ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\2ACHJTAI.ITA\packages\vs-mda
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped     ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's about the nodejs related issue.

Did a google translation and I think the error means "'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal command". So you have MySQL or related utilities installed on your machine, right? I am interested to know what it is.

This kind of error mainly cause because the command line cannot find the path to MySQL. something like "c:\program files(x86)\MySQL...\Bin".

[**A workaround**]So I will suggest you add the bin folder of MySQL server to PATH system environment variable. And try build again.

But I don't think Visual studio tools for Apache Cordova has any dependencies on MYSQL. That's why I treat above as a workaround.

I believe there must some local cache in folder like `C:\Users\<yourname>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\` or `C:\Users\<yourname>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\`

What are the content in above folders? I think it's a valuable information for Visual Studio team to get it resolved.